# Unable to Solve (for arclength parametrization)

Tags: parametric-functions

I am having trouble with Mathematica while trying to re-parametrize a curve with respect to its arclength.

I need to get the old parameter s written in terms of arclength a so the code is

```
Solve[ArcLength[r[s], {s, 0, s}] == a, s]
```

but I get

```
Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
```

What might be the cause?

Thanks.

```
r[s_] := {-(5 + 2*Cos[2*s])*Sin[3*s], (5 + 2*Cos[2*s])*Cos[3*s], 
2*Sin[2*s]}
```

Comment: Are you plan to solve for an undefined `r`?

Comment: No, I will update the post.

Comment: using the parameter `s` as it own limit doesn't make sense. Try `Solve[ArcLength[r[s], {s, 0, smax}] == a, smax]`

Comment: If I plug in smax (2*Pi), the program says:2 \[Pi] is not a valid variable. >>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can start by looking at the input to `Solve`.  Trying to evaluate

```
ArcLength[r[ss], {ss, 0, s}]
```

takes more than a minute to evaluate on my computer.  We can at least get the form by taking the integral ourselves:

```
Simplify[Norm[r'[s]], Element[s, Reals]]
(* Sqrt[259 + 180 Cos[2 s] + 18 Cos[4 s]] *)
```

Already this doesn't look promising...  The integral takes a few seconds:

```
Integrate[%, s]
```

This eventually results in a page-long expression containing lots of special functions like `EllipticE`, `EllipticF`, and `EllipticPi`, as well as tons of `I`s.  Mathematica is telling you that it doesn't think there's a closed-form solution (and I'd have to agree).

Comment: But it must be possible to parametrize this curve w/ respect to arclength. Does this mean it is not?

Comment: @user27670 Yes, there is a parameterization, however there is no closed-form solution for `s` in terms of elementary functions.  For a simple example, try solving `Sin[x] + x == 1` by hand.  A solution exists, but you can't write it in closed form.

Comment: "it doesn't think there's a closed-form solution" - it returned a closed form, but it just happened to be non-elementary.